# How do I generate the API docs/documentation for Magento?

Tags: api, magento, documentation, phpdoc

I have Magento installed and I wanted to know how to generate the full API docs, like the ones on http://docs.magentocommerce.com/ that were generated using phpdoc. Is there a configuration file included with Magento for phpdoc that I can use to generate the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual program is called phpDocumentor and you can use it on the command-line to document the core Magento code by using `phpdoc -d $MAGENTO_PATH/app/code/core/Mage/ -t docs`. Don't forget get to create a directory called docs, or you can set the target directory to whatever you want.

To document the API of an extension you can use `phpdoc -d $MAGENTO_PATH/app/code/local/$PACKAGE/$MODULE` where `$PACKAGE` is the package name, and `$MODULE` is the name of the module, and `$MAGENTO_PATH` is where Magento is installed.

Warning: it could take a while to generate *all* the API documentation as Magento is a pretty big program.